# Parsing complex JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I'm quite new with JSON and Python and trying to work with complex JSON outputs that I'm getting with GET requests. This is one example of JSON output (this is a small part of it but the principle is the same):

```
{
  "innerSet": [
    {
      "clusterUID": {
        "id": 3585057579401361143
      },
      "rpasState": [
        {
          "rpaUID": {
            "clusterUID": {
              "id": 3585057579401361143
            },
            "rpaNumber": 1
          },
          "status": "OK",
          "repositoryConnectivityStatus": {
            "accessStatus": "OK",
            "multipathingProblems": false
          },
          "remoteRPAsDataLinkStatus": [
            {
              "JsonSubType": "RPAConnectivityStatus",
              "clusterUID": {
                "id": 2671811049708195677
              },
              "entityType": "RPA",
              "connectivityStatus": "OK",
              "rpaUID": {
                "clusterUID": {
                  "id": 2671811049708195677
                },
                "rpaNumber": 1
              }
            }
          ],
         }
      ]
    }
 ]
}
```

I trying to find the best way to print a single value. For example, I need the value of "connectivityStatus". Any help will be much appreciated.

I able to pars simple JSON output. I have managed to get the entire innerSet tree:

```
x = requests.get('website.com)
d = x.json() print (d['innerSet'])
```

However, I'not able to go the lower keys. For example, getting the value for "id" key in "clusterUID":

```
print (d['innerSet']['clusterUID']['id'])
```

Results in the following error: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Regards,
Yakir.

Comment: have a look at the `json` module...

Comment: Write on google: `python json` and you'll get everything you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
import simplejson as json
data = json.loads(s)
print data['innerSet'][0]['rpasState'][0]['remoteRPAsDataLinkStatus'][0]['connectivityStatus']
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Can you explain when (and why) the path needed to contain these "[0]"? I want to be able to implement it on the rest of the JSON parsing. 

Thanks again!

Comment: The `[0]` is there because you access the first element of a list.

Comment: the square bracket following "innerSet": [   specifies that innerSet is a list, similarly rpasState, remoteRPAsDataLinkStatus.

Comment: why  use json library it throw an error?should must use simplejson?

Answer (score 1):

For complex JSON, you can user [dpath](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dpath/1.4.0) it's like Xpath but on dict.

according to your json you could parse it as:

```
print(list(dpath.util.search(t, '**/connectivityStatus', yielded=True)))
print(dpath.util.get(t, '/innerSet/0/rpasState/0/remoteRPAsDataLinkStatus/0/connectivityStatus'))

[('innerSet/0/rpasState/0/remoteRPAsDataLinkStatus/0/connectivityStatus', 'OK')]
OK
```

Comment: Thanks you too, worked as well. The first suggestion however, gave all the "connectivityStatus" key it could found (make sense). But the usage of this module is clear and simple. Thanks.

Comment: This approach it's suited for complex JSON like REST response.